# The story view and traditional view have two very different presentations of my preferred tech

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, developer-story

It's pretty minor but I personally make a big distinction between these 2 sentences:

- I like working with (story view)
- Tech you want to work with (traditional view)

The first one implies that I have worked with the listed technologies—or at least that's what I would expect as a recruiter; it's not necessarily the case with the "traditional" one. The majority of my technologies were things I hoped to work with in the future.

If it were named *I like working with*, I would have filled different technologies. By changing the label you are making some of us lie in retrospect.

And there's also the fact that I loved the idea of listing the technologies that you would like to work with. It shows what you are open to, what interests you. It says a lot about someone.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks for your report. This has been fixed and will be up with our next prod build. We'll use "tech I want to work with" instead of "tech I like working with" consistently now.

We also updated the copy on the [Job Match Preferences page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/jobsearch/current) accordingly.