# Just because I've read it doesn't mean I recommend it

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs, developer-story

When I put in all these things I had read, that was not the title of the section.  Why has it been changed in Developer Story?

Comment: Related, in the spirit of "Developer Story" telling a very different story: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339639/the-story-view-and-traditional-view-have-two-very-different-presentations-of-my

Comment: I brought this issue to the team's attention, we'll discuss it today on our weekly call. Should have an update in the next 6-8 hours.

Comment: @rla4 any update?

Comment: @Aphelion I'm not really sure what you are saying here. Are you proposing a possible solution to the problem? If so, why are you proposing it to me? I don't work on the Developer Story team. All I did was leave a comment cross-referencing an issue that I think is somewhat related, because they both concern the fact that Developer Story represents information that you've entered in a different way than the standard CV does.

Answer (score -4):

Thanks for raising it.

When we moved from CVs to Developer Stories we adapted the "Books" section into "Recommended reading" to be more focussed and to better reflect the personality of the developer.

We're going to keep "Recommended reading" for now, but you have the option to remove any books that you don't want shared on your Developer Story.

Comment: Will it remove them from the traditional view too, if I do so?

Comment: Yes, they share the same content

Comment: If you like "Recommended Reading" better, why can't you use that for the CV, too, in the interest of consistency?

Comment: So, is this [status-declined] or [status-deferred]? You say "for now", but I don't know how to measure that (beyond being 6-8, of course).